# Magento 2.3 Can't change Locale Options

Tags: magento2.3, configuration, locale

I am unable to change Locale options in Stores >> Configuration >> General tab Configurations. After saving the configurations it shows 'You saved the configuration.' but there is no change.

Flushed the cache, reindexed but still no change.
Checked console but no error in console.

[image: screenshot]

> update 1 
>   Disabled all third party extensions but it still didn't worked.

update 2 
Can't save any general configuration in Default Config store view.

Comment: which option to you have change?

Comment: Timezone and Locale both.

Comment: please clean cache and remove pub/static/ folder

Comment: disable all your third party extension or custom module, and check if it will work again. if it works , enable your third party or custom module one by one to check which is causing the issue.

Comment: Disabled all third party extensions , but still didn't worked.

Comment: Now, Getting Error in console sometimes -  Uncaught ReferenceError: Fieldset is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick ((index):1949)

Comment: @Hlren cleaned cache and removed pub/static/ folder but still didn't work.

Comment: we are still looking for solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and resolved through this page, If you are still looking for the issue just checkout this page : https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-setup-locale-state-country-magento-2.html

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because your store is in **production mode**, change it to developer mode to allow this change.

It's not a bug, it's a feature to avoid adding a location that you don't have the static files compiled to support.